# Does WS02 support Jersey services?

Tags: jersey, apache-axis, wso2

Does WS02 support Jersey services ? I am able to set up proxy services in WS02 for Axis2, would like to do the same with Jersey. Is there any documentations that talk about setting Jersey proxy services in WSo2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess when you say Jersey services - you meant to say RESTful services - JAX-RS (JSR 311). Yes, WSO2 ESB can route traffic to RESTful services as well as you can expose backend services in RESTful manner with the API element in ESB.